# Create a Process in Python that Starts After Main Process Ends

Tags: python, timer, process, termination

I have a python script named "prog.py". I want to add a feature that opens a new process that watches the operation of the current script. When the script terminates, the process recognizes the termination and then invokes a certain function. Here is a pseudo-code:

```
while (script is active):    

    sleep(1) # check its status once a second

func()
```

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason the other process needs to be launched first? Seems like you could do this more efficiently and reliably by just [`exec`ing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl) when the first process completes. For example:

```
import atexit
import os

atexit.register(os.execlp, 'afterexitscript.py', 'afterexitscript.py', 'arg1', 'arg2')
```

When the current Python process exits, it will seamlessly replace itself with your other script, which need not go to the trouble of including a polling loop. Or you could just use [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) to execute whatever `func` is directly in your main script and avoid a new Python launch.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.  Just use `atexit`, and don't bother with processes unless there is a specific reason you have to.

Comment: The problem is with the following note in atexit documentation: 
" The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called."

I'm looking for a solution that work in any case of script termination...

Comment: @CrazySynthax: In that case, it would still be simpler to have the monitor process manage the "main" process, rather than the "main" process spawning a monitor that then tries to monitor the main process in turn. The former is a dead simple use of `subprocess`, the latter involves generally non-portable OS specific process detach steps and rigmarole.